# Excel vba to remove duplicate column in Excel depending on criteria

Tags: sharepoint-2010, excel, vba

I found this link https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29021/import-sharepoint-list-into-excel-using-vba-only
that people have been successfully using to automate the exporting SharePoint 2010 list items to Excel 2010.  I m able to get Excel sheet with my SharePoint data. The problem is I already had ID as a field in my SharePoint list. The vba code auto generates ID(auto incremental) and adds it in the excel file. Now I have two ID field names in my excel. I want to get rid of excel vba auto generated ID and only have the field names(ID is one of them) from my SharePoint list. How would I do that? Thanks.

```
Sub TestMacro() 
Dim objMyList As ListObject 
Dim objWksheet As Worksheet 
Dim strSPServer As String 
Const SERVER As String = "http://abcd/" 
Const LISTNAME As String = "{A486016E-80B2-44C3-8B4A-8394574B9430}" 
Const VIEWNAME As String = "" 
' The SharePoint server URL pointing to 
' the SharePoint list to import into Excel. 
strSPServer = "http://" & SERVER & "/_vti_bin" 
' Add a new worksheet to the active workbook. 
Set objWksheet = Worksheets.Add 
' Add a list range to the newly created worksheet 
' and populated it with the data from the SharePoint list. 
    Set objMyList = objWksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcExternal, _ Array(strSPServer,    LISTNAME, VIEWNAME),  
True, , Range("a1")) 
Set objMyList = Nothing 
Set objWksheet = Nothing 
End Sub
```

Comment: `objWksheet.Columns(x).Delete` where x is the unwanted column number

Comment: or, building on Tim's suggestion, objMyList.ListColumns(x).Delete, where x is the name, or index, of the table column.  I'm curious, though, where the column is being added in the vba.  I don't see any code that does that.

Comment: Thanks to you both for suggestions. Right now my excel sheet looks like this: Columns A   B   C    D    E    F    G etc. The value of A1 is ID which is excel generated and is auto incrementing. The value of B1 is also ID which is one of the fields in my SharePoint 2010 list. I am not quite sure what should be placed in the value of x in the given below lines:objWksheet.Columns(x).Delete  and objMyList.ListColumns(x).Delete . I tried putting A in place of x but in either case it showed error "Application-defined or object-defined error". How can we find the index of column A in the Excel 2010?

Comment: Use the number 1 for the 1st column.  This would be true for either example.

Comment: If you don't understand something like the columns property, then first try using the help file then try google, then finally ask at online forums.  This way you will get the info you required faster and learn along the way.  How to use column property:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214202(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: Thanks Reafidy for the link. @Doug Glancy, in my above code, the columns are being written after Set objMyList = objWksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcExternal, _ Array(strSPServer,    LISTNAME, VIEWNAME),   True, , Range("a1"))  I put your line of code right after this line and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar to what you're doing, and I added the following lines of code:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

The .RefreshAll refreshes the table's data, and when it's refreshed, it removes that column.  I'm still currently trying to figure out why, but it does solve the issue of getting rid of that column.

Edit: I know this is answering a question from 3 years ago, but thought it might help those who stumble across this question.